# Get an Auth code from ms graph for an application - returning error about missing request_type

Tags: oauth-2.0, httprequest, power-automate, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a Power Automate flow to get MS Booking information.  Having trouble with getting an Authorization using https://login.microsoftonline.com/***TENANT ID****/oauth2/token.  I receive an error that I am missing grant_type although I supply it.  I registered the app in azure, the HTTP request in power automate looks like this:

[image]

{
"uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
"content-type  ": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
},
"body": "client_id=&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&grant_type=password&client_secret=&username=username&password=password"

I receive the error:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong or missing?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be some spaces in your body value? Can you try it in the order below: `grant_type=password&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&client_id=@{variables('App ID')}&username=@{variables('Email')}&password=@{outputs('YourComposeActionName')}&client_secret=@{outputs('YourSecondComposeActionName')}` Also have a look at this article, https://laurakokkarinen.com/calling-microsoft-graph-from-microsoft-flow-and-other-daemon-apps-with-delegated-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick follow-up. Thanks Expiscornpvus, you pointed me in the right direction, although there were spaces after the content type header, I corrected this and things worked well